# hamburger menu is not working and its overflowing

Tags: css, reactjs

```
 // App.js

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
    <label className="hamburger-menu">
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </label>
    <div className="logo">Purohit Store</div>
    <div className="nav-lists">
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>products</li>
            <li>contact</li>
            <li>about</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <button>login</button>
          <button>cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;


// App.css

*, *::before, *::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar,
.nav-lists,
.navbar ul,
.nav-lists div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav-lists{
  gap: 50px;
}
.navbar ul,
.nav-lists div{
  gap: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 701px) {
.hamburger-menu{
  display: none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

.nav-lists{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: translate 200ms ease;
  translate: 100%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.nav-lists ul,
.nav-lists div{
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 110;
}

.hamburger-menu:has(input:checked) + .nav-lists {
  translate: 0;
}

}

[enter image description here][1]
```

when i check the checkbox nav-lists should be translate to 0 and when i uncheck the checkbox it should translate to 100% but it does not working and nav-lists is overflowing so in body i set overflow is hidden but still it is overflowing.
when i do the same thing with navbar it's working but the problem is that app logo and hamburger both included in navbar so i do this with nav-lists but in nav-lists it doesn't work.
when i exclude logo and hamburger from navbar and paste it to top of the jsx and include all jsx in one fragment than its working but when i include all this jsx in div instead of jsx fragment it does not work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator: _"The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element **only if it immediately follows the first element**"_ - not the case here, `.nav-lists` does not immediately follow `.hamburger-menu`, you got `.logo` in between the two. So you would need to use the _general sibling combinator_ instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is this selector:

`.hamburger-menu:has(input:checked) + .nav-lists`

The `+` is looking for the element that immediately follows the hamburger (which in your case, isn't `nav-lists`, it's `logo`)

You can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~` to match any following element:

`.hamburger-menu:has(input:checked) ~ .nav-lists`

Mini example:

```css
.hamburger-menu:has(input:checked) ~ .nav-lists {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<label class="hamburger-menu">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
<div class="anotherElement">Another element</div>
<div class="nav-lists">Nav list</div>
```